# If $R$ is an integral domain without $1_R$ and $a=b$, then $ac \neq b$ for every $c$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

As it says in the question, let $a = b$, where $a, b \neq 0$.
Assume by contradiction that there exists some $c \in R$ such that $ac = b$. Then,
$a=ac$, so $a-ac = 0$. I was thinking about using distributive property, but this cannot be applied properly since it forces the existence of $1_R \in R$, i.e. $a(1_R-c) = 0$. Is there an alternate way to prove the statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ac=a\neq 0$ then $acc=ac$ implies $c^2=c$ is a nonzero idempotent.

Then $(x-xc)c=0=c(x-cx)$. Implies $x=cx=xc$ for any $x\in R$. That would mean $c$ is an identity element.

Since you assumed there is no identity, the original assumption that $ac=a$ for some $c$ cannot be true for any $c$.